# Migrating PHP \ MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cloud

We have been running our PHP applications on CentOS \ MySQL dedicated servers for sometime.

However, I now have a requirement from a client that we are highly fault tolerant and able to scale up quickly and easily.

What is involved in migrating from a dedicated Linux server environment to cloud based technology? Is it a steep learning curve or are most of the differences under the hood.

Comment: Please define 'cloud based technology', you mean moving to a PaaS or an IaaS? Since you are comming from a dedicated server and you have the knoledge of 'configuring things' it will not be much of a problem.

Comment: It really depends on what solution you're pursuing. Is it MySQL Cluster? Percona? [Amazon RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/)?

Comment: I think PaaS and am looking at AWS

Comment: You have to consider that AWS does not provide pure PaaS services. You have to look if OpsWorks applies to your case. Also you said 'highly fault tolerant' which mean a type of horizontal scale. You have to be sure tha your application can scale horizontaly, meaning that you may have to change your code.

Comment: I think I really need to consult with someone who has a lot of experience with cloud based solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily take your PHP application to cloud by creating your own PaaS. Apache Stratos is a PaaS framework which allows you to do so. It has out of the box support for PHP and MySQL (those are called cartridges). It guarantees high availability and autoscaling support and also load balancing. You dont need to change your application code either.

Comment: Thank you Amila, would you be willing to assist me on a consultancy basis. If so, please can you send your details to michael@andromob.com